# How do we put labels to this matrix as shown in colors?

Tags: matrices, tikz-matrix

[image]

The code that I am currently using is below

```
\begin{equation*}
\mathsf{L} ~~=~~
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1\\
1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is with use `nicematrix` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    \[
\mathsf{L} =
    \begin{bNiceArrayC}{CC}[code-for-last-col = \color{red}\small]
1 &  0  & A \\
0 & -1  & B \\
1 &  1  & C \\
1 &  1  & D
    \end{bNiceArrayC}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An old method - peraphs primitive - but it works is the use of two matrix. One with bracket and another without bracket. After you can add a random (basic) color using `xcolor` package. I have put a low size for the text, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathsf{L} =\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  0 \\
0 & -1 \\
1 &  1 \\
1 &  1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{matrix}
{\scriptstyle \textcolor{red}{A}}\\
{\scriptstyle \textcolor{red}{B}}\\
{\scriptstyle \textcolor{red}{C}}\\
{\scriptstyle \textcolor{red}{D}}
\end{matrix}\]
\end{document}
```